How do I prevent an infinite loading loop in the AuthProvider using Firebase?
I am working on a project with Remix, Firebase and Chakra, and I am trying to fix an issue where my project is briefly flashing unstyled HTML (FOUC) when navigating pages.
I think the issue arises when the initial user state is set to null and doesn't finish loading before displaying the new page. When I add a loading element, it gets stuck in an infinite loading loop, where it just displays the loading div and never actually loads the page. What could be the cause of this issue?
import React, { useEffect, useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, User } from "firebase/auth";
import PageLoading from "~/components/ui/pageLoading";

type AuthContextProps = {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}

type AuthContextType = {
    user: User | null;
    loading: boolean;
    setUser: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<User | null>>;
};

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType | undefined>(undefined);

export const useAuth = () => {
    const context = useContext(AuthContext);
    if (!context) {
        throw new Error("useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider");
    }
    return context;
};

export function AuthProvider({ children }: AuthContextProps) {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
            setUser(currentUser); // Set user whether logged in or out
            setLoading(false); // Set loading to false after setting user
            console.log("User state in AuthProvider:", currentUser);
        });

        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, [auth]);


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("AuthProvider user state:", user);
        console.log("AuthProvider loading state:", loading);
    }, [user, loading]);

    if (loading) {
        return <div>Loading from Auth Provider...</div>;
    }

    const values = {
        user,
        loading,
        setUser,
    }

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={values}>
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
}

AuthProvider is then being wrapped around the entire application in the root.tsx file, as so -
// Layout component that provides the main HTML structure
export function Layout({ styles }: { styles: string }) {
  const [colorScheme, setColorScheme] = useState("light");

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch theme from client-specific storage or logic, e.g., localStorage
    const storedColorScheme = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "light";
    setColorScheme(storedColorScheme);
  }, []);

  return (
    <html style={{ backgroundColor: "rgb(248, 244, 240)", colorScheme: "light" }} lang="en" data-theme={colorScheme}>
      <head>
        <Meta />
        <Links />
        <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: styles }} />
      </head>
      <body suppressHydrationWarning>
        <AuthProvider>
          <SidebarProvider>
            <ColorModeScript />
            <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
              <AppLayout>
                <Outlet />
              </AppLayout>
              <ScrollRestoration />
              <Scripts />
            </ChakraProvider>
          </SidebarProvider>
        </AuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

// Main app entry point, can be used for route-specific content
export default function App() {
  return (
    null
  );
}

When the page loads, the console displays 'AuthProvider user state: null, AuthProvider loading state: true', and then displays 'User state in AuthProvider: currentUser', with the necessary user data from Firebase. It seems like that's why there's a brief flash (fouc)- because the user state is set to null before it has a chance to load.

This code you've shared looks fine to me, I don't see any overt issues with it. Can you [edit] to share where and how AuthProvider is being rendered to provide readers a more complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

"it gets stuck in an infinite loading loop" When you run your code in a debugger, does your onAuthStateChanged callback ever get called? In other words, does the console.log("User state in AuthProvider:", currentUser); ever execute and print something?

@FrankvanPuffelen when the page loads, the console displays 'AuthProvider user state: null, AuthProvider loading state: true', and then displays 'User state in AuthProvider: currentUser', with the necessary user data from Firebase. It seems like that's why there's a brief flash (fouc)- because the user state is set to null before it has a chance to load.
See screenshot of console here - console log (ibb.co link)

Do you see any actual render looping, or are the useEffect hooks maybe only running twice due to rendering the app into a React.StrictMode component? I see what looks like 2 initial sets of logs from when AuthProvider mounted and rendered, then the logs from the onAuthStateChanged callback, then another set of logs from AuthProvider after the states updated. This all looks rather normal to me.

Yeah, it sounds to me like the expected behavior: when the page loads, Firebase immediately starts to restore the user's authentication state from the locally stored credentials. This requires it to make a call to the server though (a.o. to check if the account was disabled), which happens asynchronously. Until this call has completed the auth state is unknown, and the currentUser will be null. This phase is likely what you perceive as a "flash". The only way to work around this is to keep your own "is this user likelty signed in" state, and then use that to direct to the signed-in route.
